gmail for bounce and activities "
wp 6.4.5 civi 5.77.1
I have painstakingly followed the oauth instructions and enabled imap in google account settings but on testing either bounce or email to activities I get the  error below -
how do I trouble shoot please?
2024-10-03 16:49:54+1000  [warning] MailSettings: Failed to read test message
Array
(
[exception] => Error: "Call to undefined function getmypid()"
#0 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/zetacomponents/mail/src/parts/multipart.php(83): ezcMailMultipart::generateBoundary()
#1 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/zetacomponents/mail/src/parts/multiparts/multipart_alternative.php(67): ezcMailMultipart->__construct((Array:0))
#2 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/zetacomponents/mail/src/parser/parts/multipart_alternative_parser.php(51): ezcMailMultipartAlternative->__construct()
#3 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/zetacomponents/mail/src/parser/interfaces/part_parser.php(192): ezcMailMultipartAlternativeParser->__construct(Object(ezcMailHeadersHolder))
#4 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/zetacomponents/mail/src/parser/parts/rfc822_parser.php(110): ezcMailPartParser::createPartParserForHeaders(Object(ezcMailHeadersHolder))
#5 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/zetacomponents/mail/src/parser/parser.php(252): ezcMailRfc822Parser->parseBody("\r\n")
#6 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Mailing/MailStore.php(175): ezcMailParser->parseMail(Object(ezcMailImapSet))
#7 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/ext/civi_mail/Civi/Api4/Action/MailSettings/TestConnection.php(55): CRM_Mailing_MailStore->fetchNext(5)
#8 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/BasicBatchAction.php(95): Civi\Api4\Action\MailSettings\TestConnection->doTask((Array:2))
#9 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/BasicBatchAction.php(78): Civi\Api4\Generic\BasicBatchAction->processBatch(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\Result), (Array:1))
#10 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Provider/ActionObjectProvider.php(70): Civi\Api4\Generic\BasicBatchAction->_run(Object(Civi\Api4\Generic\Result))
#11 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/API/Kernel.php(153): Civi\Api4\Provider\ActionObjectProvider->invoke(Object(Civi\Api4\Action\MailSettings\TestConnection))
#12 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(256): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Object(Civi\Api4\Action\MailSettings\TestConnection))
#13 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/api/api.php(91): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute()
#14 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Admin/Form/MailSettings.php(241): civicrm_api4("MailSettings", "testConnection", (Array:1))
#15 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(646): CRM_Admin_Form_MailSettings->postProcess()
#16 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(153): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#17 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Upload.php(120): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->realPerform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_MailSettings), "upload")
#18 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Upload->perform(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_MailSettings), "upload")
#19 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Admin_Form_MailSettings), "upload")
#20 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(355): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("upload")
#21 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(98): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#22 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(299): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run("CRM_Admin_Form_MailSettings", "Mail Accounts", (Array:0))
#23 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:17))
#24 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#25 /www/website/public/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1232): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#26 /www/website/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke("")
#27 /www/website/public/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters("", (Array:1))
#28 /www/website/public/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#29 /www/website/public/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action("toplevel_page_CiviCRM")
#30 {main}
